# Call function from element inserted from Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to invoke a javascript function from some HTML code inserted by some other javascript code (see below).

```
$(".leave-a-note").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).closest('li').attr('id');
            $('#' + id).children('.write-comment-space').html("<a class='save-comment' href='#' onClick='insertComment();'>Save</a> <a href='#'>Cancel</a>");});
```

When I try to call a function from the ".save-comment" url nothing happens.

```
$(".save-comment").click(function() {
            console.log("test");
        });
```

However, if I leave the ".save-comment" URL directly in my HTML the function works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use delegated event like this as html is generated after the DOM is loaded:

```
$(document).on("click",".save-comment",function() {
            console.log("test");
        });
```

Comment: Why this has been downvoted? Could use closest static container but anyway...

Comment: Op did'nt showed much html content so i use document